# How to serve static assets from custom folders in phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework

I want to use ckeditor in my phoenix project.

If I place ckeditor files in /web/static/assets/ckeditor, the ckeditor folder gets copied to /priv/static, but if I access the file at http://localhost:4000/ckeditor/ckeditor.js it shows me a

> no route found for GET /ckeditor/ckeditor.js

However, if I move the whole of ckeditor folder underneath a folder of the standard name (js, css, image) then it gets served.

The static assets documentation http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets suggested that anything placed there would be copied over and served. But seems like only js/css/image/font folders are getting served, not any custom named folder.

How can I have these files be served?

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at the Plug.Static config in `lib/YOUR_APP/endpoint.ex`

Here's the default:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/"
  only: ~w(css fonts images js sitemaps favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

You can add additional folders to the `only` list and they'll be served as well.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the docs https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html

Comment: This (and the docs) doesn't explain how one can generate the URL with the digest hash included to for example display an image.